# Actual address of COM object in C#

Tags: c#, pointers, com, interop, marshalling

I have a COM object for which I am trying to get the actual underlying address of, so I can get the address of the vtable. I need this to be a valid numerical address because I need to be able to add to it. For example, if I want to call the third function in the vtable, I need to be able to call something like:

`Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(vtableaddr + (3 * 8), ...)`;//3rd entry, 8 byte pointers in 64-bit mode.

to call the third function in the vtable.

That is, I need to be able to do addition on the pointer addresses.

The reason I specify *actual* in the question title, is that all of the standard ways of getting the underlying object address don't seem to be returning a real address.

```
var item = /*... my COM object */;
var pUnk = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(item);
var pVtbl = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(pUnk);
```

When running this code, both `pUnk` and `pVtbl` will have very large numerical values in them. Something like 0x1F3110D7948 which is 2,143,474,776,392. My system definitely does not have two trillion bytes of RAM. So I am assuming that pointer is containing additional information in the high bytes?

I have also tried code like:

```
var gch = GCHandle.Alloc(pUnk, GCHandleType.Pinned);
var intptr = gch.AddrOfPinnedObject();
var pVtbl = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(intptr);
```

and get similarly large numbers. Calling `GCHandle.ToIntPtr(gch)` doesn't help either.

So I need to know how to do get the *real* address in memory of where the underlying COM object is actually stored.

PS: I know this is a non-standard way of doing things, but please understand that I absolutely *must* be able to get these addresses in this manner for the project I am working on. This is a critical showstopper.

Comment: "but please understand that I absolutely must be able to get ...." that sounds more like a tantrum then an argument. Just tell us why and we might help if we are able to.

Comment: No tantrum. The reason I specified that is sometimes when you ask about doing things in a non-standard way, the answer is that you shouldn't be doing it that way. I was trying to clarify that despite this being a very strange and non-standard way to do this, these are the requirements I'm stuck with.

Comment: First, linear addresses that you are seeing are not physical. They don't have to be smaller than the installed memory. Look up virtual memory. Second, what is this for? I sense an XY problem.